# How to remove confirm password field?

Tags: magento2, module, validation, registration

I want to remove the confirm password validation field in my registration form. How could I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change two places

Comment **password confirmation field** in `Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`

```
    <div class="field confirmation required">
        <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Change the below line in `Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`

**from**

```
$this->checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation);
```

**to**

```
if(isset($confirmation))
{
    $this->checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation);
}
```

**Info:** Don't change core file directly, you must override the above files from your custom **module/theme**.

Answer (score 2):

Go to following location and comment the below code

```
<div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __('Confirm Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
</div>
```

/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement and I did the following

Overriden `module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` in my module

Change

```
<input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
```

And added following in the script

```
$('#password').change(function() {
    $('#password-confirmation').val($(this).val());
});
```